# Saving changes to excel workbook with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do you write the code to save an excel workbook that has VBA code, as I want to upload this to One Drive and collaborate with other people and see their changes to the form as they edit.

Comment: you record a macro of the save action

Comment: To record their changes, you need to add Worksheet events. Prefer to be logging on hidden worksheet. Assuming their Excel settings are set to run your macro.

Comment: If you have code that tries to do that and doesn't work, show us your code. Otherwise you could start by googling pretty much exactly that question title to get an idea how to do it.

Comment: I think the op is talking about co-authoring. That's going to be beyond VBA. But MS have just introduced this feature to Office 365 subs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement, then hat's likely going to be beyond VBA's capabilities. But if you've got an Office 365 subscripton then Microsoft have built in a new sharing feature called *co-authoring* that you could use to accomplish this.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collaborate-on-Excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Hi, yes the new sharing feature is what I meant, but the excel sheet itself won't let me save changes even if I don't share. Every time I make a change to the sheet and close it then re-open, all my changes are gone.